# Rake aborted! Uninitialized constant User

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I ran into some problem when making adjustments to my DB, so I went to a previous commit, but now when I run

```
rake db:drop
rake db:create
rake db:migrate
```

I get the error:

```
rake aborted!
uninitialized constant User
/Users/Marcus/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/activesupport-3.2.3/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:229:in `block in constantize'
/Users/Marcus/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/activesupport-3.2.3/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:228:in `each'
/Users/Marcus/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/activesupport-3.2.3/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:228:in `constantize'
```

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: Sounds like somewhere in your code you are referencing a `User` model, and in this particular commit, it does not exist.